# How to replace \\ in a string with \ in scala?

Tags: scala, typesafe

I am trying to parse a file using typesafe config in scala. The file has key value pairs to be loaded as configurations in my application.
The is key is a regex.
Ex: `"ASD\\.KL.*\\." = "somevalue"`
The regex has to be loaded as `"ASD\.KL.*\."`
It does not work with typesafe config factory but works with Properties Configuration.
So Im trying to replace `"ASD\\.KL.*\\.".replaceAll("\\\\","\\")` but this doesnot work  too.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do a specific replace, you should use unescape the "raw" string to get respective Java/Scala String as it will take care of the "raw"-ness of any raw string and not just your special case.

Add following dependency for commons-lang`,

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-lang" % "commons-lang" % "2.6"
```

Now, you can use `StringEscapeUtils` provided by `commons-lang`

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

val rawString = raw"ASD\\.KL.*\\."
// rawString: String = ASD\\.KL.*\\.

val requiredString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(rawString)
// requiredString: String = ASD\.KL.*\.
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to match a literal `\` character, you have to use the regex `\\` as `\` has a special meaning in regular expressions and needs to be escaped.

In order to *write* the regex `\\` you have to use `"\\\\"` as `\` has a special meaning in Java (and Scala) Strings and needs to be escaped. Alternatively, you can use `raw"\\"` for the same regex.

In order to match two consecutive `\\`, you have to use `"\\\\\\\\"` as a String (or `raw"\\\\"`).

The character `\` has also a special meaning in the replacement part of `replaceAll` and needs to be escaped as well, according to the JavaDoc

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

This is what it looks like in the end

```
scala> import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Matcher

scala> val s = raw"ASD\\.KL.*\\."
s: String = ASD\\.KL.*\\.

scala> s.replaceAll(raw"\\\\", Matcher.quoteReplacement(raw"\"))
res0: String = ASD\.KL.*\.

scala> s.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"))
res1: String = ASD\.KL.*\.
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"ASD\\.KL.*\\.".replace("\\", "/");
```

***or***

```
var tmp = "ASD\\.KL.*\\."; 
tmp.replace("\\", "/");
```